# Google App Engine Python - Simple REST handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest

I have a scenario where a client (mobile app) would send an update query to my GAE website to see if the website has a newer version of a resource and if it does it would return this resource (zip-file) otherwise it would just return a json response "all up to date" (or perhaps a Not Modified 304 HTTP response code)

How should the REST URL look (coming from the mobile app)?

`www.example.com/update?version=(client_version)`

OR

`www.example.com/update_client_version`

Thankful for any help I can get.

What I have so far is... but I'm getting a 404 for some reason when doing `http://localhost:8080/update/1`

`INFO     2012-11-22 10:12:18,441 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /holidays/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

```
class UpdateHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, version):

        latestVersion == 1

        if version == latestVersion:
            self.response.write('You are using latest version')
        else:
            self.response.write('You are not using latest version')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/update/(.*)', UpdateHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Both are okay. This is not a very specific python or appengine question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the following approach:

> www.example.com/update/client_version

Your code should look like this:

```
import webapp2

class UpdateHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, version):
        # Do something for version

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [(r'/update/(\d+)', UpdateHandler)], 
    debug=True)
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when I try this. (`INFO     2012-11-22 10:12:18,441 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /update/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 -`)

Comment: See my updated answer please. I forgot that you are using webapp and not webapp2.

Comment: Ok, so if the user is not using the latest version how would I serve the user (mobile client) with a file.zip that resides on the server?

Comment: Supposing that you use the Blobstore, you can serve the file using [Blobstore Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview).

Comment: It's just a small zip file (max 20-30kb). Blobstore seems like overkill? How can I just refer to the zip-file in a directory?

Comment: Then, you can store this file into a `BlobProperty` in the Datastore. In this case, you can serve the file as follows: 

`self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/zip" `
`self.response.headers["Content-Disposition"] =  "attachment;filename=filename.zip" `
`self.response.out.write(your_entity.blob_property) `

Comment: I did this instead: `f = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/file.zip', 'r') self.response.write(f.read())`

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use HTTP 304, you should see if you can get the client to make a conditional GET request. E.g. add a header `If-Modified-Since: Thu, 22 Nov 2012 09:24:52 GMT`.